# TypeError trying to concatenate list

Tags: python, gradient-descent

I'm trying to solve this exercise about gradient descent. When I run my code I get an error on: `yi_pred = xi * m + c`.

```
def gradient_descent(x, y, m, c, epochs, L=0.001):
    x_new =[]
    for elem in x:
        x_new.extend(elem)
        y =[]
    for i in range(epochs):
            DM = []
            DC = []
            for num, xi in enumerate(x):
                yi_pred = xi * m + c
                yi = y[num]
                di_m = xi * (yi_pred - yi)
                di_c = yi_pred - yi
                DM.append(di_m)
                DC.append(di_c)
                dm = sum(DM)/len(DM)
                dc = sum(DC)/len(DC)
            m = m - L * dm
            c = c - L * dc

    return m,c
```

Data:

```
x = [[0.18], [1.0], [0.92], [0.07], [0.85], [0.99], [0.87]]
y = [[109.85], [155.72], [137.66], [76.17], [139.75], [162.6], [151.77]]
m = 0
c = 0
epochs = 200
```

The error is: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a nested list.

Remove the extra square brackets '[]' from `x` and `y`:

```
x = [0.18, 1.0, 0.92, 0.07, 0.85, 0.99, 0.87]
y = [109.85, 155.72, 137.66, 76.17, 139.75, 162.6, 151.77]
```